# Adjusting Bootstrap "input-group" Respective Widths

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap v3.3.4, I am attempting to create an input-group to represent something like a phone number.

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" id="long-item" class="form-control" />
                <div class="input-group-addon">Ext</div>
                <input type="text" id="short-item" class="form-control" />
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I get is the following:

[image: What I get]

However, I don't want both sides to be equal. I want the first text box to be about 3 times wider than the second, as you might expect in a phone number.

Using CSS to style them by id, I can reduce the width of either side, but it ends up looking like this:

[image: What I get with CSS]

```
#long-item{
    width:70%
}

#short-item{
    width:30%
}
```

This doesn't work, because it messes up the overall "apparent" width of the input-group and leaves that huge gap. Obviously, width isn't the right thing to use here.

What do I need to do to adjust their widths so that one text input is larger than the other, but they both fill the allotted column space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further tinkering, I determined that the following code will serve my purposes:

```
#short-item{
    width: 3em;
}
```

[image]

It does not keep the ratio during form resizes, but it keeps the shorter box the size I wanted. The larger box expands and contracts with the form, as per its nestling in the col-md-3 div.

Edit: However, I also noticed that this width cannot be applied to the left text input. We again get that weird shortness and gap that I saw in changing the widths by percentages.

I hope this helps someone else.